# No sound on fresh install of Debian 12

Tags: debian, audio, alsa, intel, pipewire

I have no sound on a fresh debian 12 install on a mini-pc. The PC is connected via HDMI to a TV. I've tried testing with pipewire, with alsa-only, with pipewire-pulse. I also tried testing plugging in headphones via the AUX port. There is never any sound

## hardware info

```
█[coolby][~][0]$ inxi
CPU: dual core Intel Celeron N3350 (-MCP-) speed/min/max: 2391/800/2400 MHz
Kernel: 6.1.0-17-amd64 x86_64 Up: 1d 21h 29m Mem: 1786.0/5773.7 MiB (30.9%)
Storage: 58.23 GiB (22.5% used) Procs: 191 Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.26
█[coolby][~][0]$ inxi -SAG
System:
  Host: coolby Kernel: 6.1.0-17-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: N/A
    Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 500 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 500 (APL
    2)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.0-17-amd64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 status: active
█[coolby][~][0]$
```

## os

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm
```

## firmware

```
[coolby][~][1]$ sudo journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: snd_soc_skl 0000:00:0e.0: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: use msi interrupt mode
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: NHLT_DEVICE_I2S detected, ssp_mask 0x1
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: Overriding topology with MCLK mask 0x2 from NHLT
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: hda codecs found, mask 4
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/sof/sof-apl.ri
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk mask 0x0
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk SSP0
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/sof-tplg/sof-apl-es8336-ssp0.tplg
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: input: sof-essx8336 Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input21
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input22
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input23
Jan 27 03:43:17 coolby kernel: input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input24
```

## pavucontrol

Pavucontrol via pipewire-pulse appears to show the sound bar moving but there is no sound, even after switching to various outputs and configurations.

[image: Pavucontrol via pipewire-pulse]

There is no "HDMI" configuration or profile, only "Speakers" and "Pro Audio", neither of which appears to deliver any sound:
[image: Pavucontrol configurations]

## sound cards

```
█[coolby][~][0]$ sudo cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [sofessx8336    ]: sof-essx8336 - sof-essx8336
                      intel-AB2L-Defaultstring
```

```
█[coolby][~][130]$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 0: ES8336 (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 5: HDMI 1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 6: HDMI 2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofessx8336 [sof-essx8336], device 7: HDMI 3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
█[coolby][~][0]$
```

`aplay -L` list several cards, none of which contains `HDMI` in their name:

```
█[coolby][~][1]$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
lavrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Libav/FFmpeg Library
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pipewire
    PipeWire Sound Server
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
speex
    Plugin using Speex DSP (resample, agc, denoise, echo, dereverb)
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)
hw:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=0
    sof-essx8336,
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=5
    sof-essx8336,
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=6
    sof-essx8336,
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=7
    sof-essx8336,
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=0
    sof-essx8336,
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=5
    sof-essx8336,
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=6
    sof-essx8336,
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=7
    sof-essx8336,
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=sofessx8336
    sof-essx8336,
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=0
    sof-essx8336,
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=5
    sof-essx8336,
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=6
    sof-essx8336,
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=sofessx8336,DEV=7
    sof-essx8336,
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=sofessx8336
    sof-essx8336
    USB Stream Output
█[coolby][~][0]$
```

I tried piping each one of those sound cards through speaker-test, but there was never a sound. I also plugged in speakers/headphones via the AUX cable, no sound.

Also, `pactl list-sinks` only lists a single card:

```
█[coolby][~][0]$ pactl list sinks
Sink #41
        State: IDLE
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0-platform-sof-essx8336.stereo-fallback
        Description: Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster Stereo
        Driver: PipeWire
        Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 4294967295
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 47038 /  72% / -8.64 dB,   front-right: 47038 /  72% / -8.64 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0-platform-sof-essx8336.stereo-fallback.monitor
        Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
        Properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "sof-essx8336"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sof_es8336"
                alsa.id = "ES8336 (*)"
                alsa.long_card_name = "intel-AB2L-Defaultstring"
                alsa.name = ""
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                api.alsa.card.longname = "intel-AB2L-Defaultstring"
                api.alsa.card.name = "sof-essx8336"
                api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
                api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
                api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
                audio.channels = "2"
                audio.position = "FL,FR"
                card.profile.device = "6"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                device.id = "40"
                device.profile.description = "Stereo"
                device.profile.name = "stereo-fallback"
                device.routes = "2"
                factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
                media.class = "Audio/Sink"
                device.description = "Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster"
                node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0-platform-sof-essx8336.stereo-fallback"
                node.nick = "Stereo"
                node.pause-on-idle = "false"
                object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:hw:0:playback"
                priority.driver = "1000"
                priority.session = "1000"
                factory.id = "18"
                clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
                client.id = "33"
                node.driver = "true"
                factory.mode = "merge"
                audio.adapt.follower = ""
                library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
                object.id = "41"
                object.serial = "41"
                node.max-latency = "4096/48000"
                api.alsa.period-size = "1024"
                api.alsa.period-num = "8"
                api.alsa.headroom = "0"
                api.acp.auto-port = "false"
                api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
                api.alsa.card = "0"
                api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
                api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:0e.0-platform-sof-essx8336"
                device.enum.api = "udev"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
                device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0-platform-sof-essx8336"
                device.nick = "sof-essx8336"
                device.plugged.usec = "30160517"
                device.product.id = "0x5a98"
                device.product.name = "Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster"
                device.subsystem = "sound"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sof-essx8336/sound/card0"
                device.vendor.id = "0x8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.string = "0"
        Ports:
                analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, not available)
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, availability group: Legacy 1, availability unknown)
        Active Port: analog-output-headphones
        Formats:
                pcm
```

## Display

The system is connected via HDMI to a TV with speakers, sound on this TV works fine with other devices:

```
█[coolby][~][0]$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 853mm x 480mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1920x1080i    60.00    59.94
   1680x1050     59.88
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1440x900      59.90
   1280x960      60.00
   1360x768      60.02
   1280x800      59.91
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   720x480i      60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
█[coolby][~][0]$
```

## speaker test

These appear to succeed but there is no sound.

```
█[coolby][~][1]$ speaker-test -l5 -D plughw:0,5

speaker-test 1.2.8

Playback device is plughw:0,5
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 96 to 16384
Period size range from 48 to 4096
Using max buffer size 16384
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 4096
was set buffer_size = 16384
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.646839
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.985025
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986957
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986913
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.985883
█[coolby][~][0]$ speaker-test -l5 -D plughw:0,6

speaker-test 1.2.8

Playback device is plughw:0,6
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 96 to 16384
Period size range from 48 to 4096
Using max buffer size 16384
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 4096
was set buffer_size = 16384
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.645836
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.985933
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.986965
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.986956
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.981944
█[coolby][~][0]$ speaker-test -l5 -D plughw:0,7

speaker-test 1.2.8

Playback device is plughw:0,7
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 96 to 16384
Period size range from 48 to 4096
Using max buffer size 16384
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 4096
was set buffer_size = 16384
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.646129
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.986089
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.986616
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.986962
 0 - Unknown
Time per period = 2.984837
█[coolby][~][0]$
```

## Product details

`Coolby Yealbox MINI PC Intel Celeron N3350 Processor Windows 10 system 6GB RAM 64GB ROM M.2 Slot 4K HD Office Desktop MINI Computer`

```
Details
Save
Report this item
Power Mode: Power Supply
Operating Voltage: 110V/220V
Plug Specification: US Plug
Connectivity Technology: USB
CPU Manufacturer: Intel
Wireless Communication Standard: 2.4 ghz radio frequency
Processor Type: Intel Celeron*
Graphics Processor Manufacturer: Intel
Graphics Type: Integrated
Usage: Multimedia
Wireless Connection Type: Wifi
Hard Drive Type: Ssd
Graphics Processor: Inteluhdgraphics600
Memory Technology: Ddr3
Operating System: Windows10pro
Graphics Card Interface: Integrated
Total Video Out Ports: 1
Battery Properties: Without Battery
Brand: Coolby
Connectivity Type: None
Wireless Property: With Wi-Fi function
```

[image: product info]
How can I further troubleshoot audio on this mini PC?

Comment: What does aplay -l (minus L) tells ? alternatively could you please update your question with the results of *cat /proc/asound/cards* ?

Comment: added the info under "sound cards"

Comment: Ok then, since you mention some HDMI hardware link, can we presume that card 0, **device 5 (or 6 or 7)** should be linked to the default sound device (v.g. and **not** card 0 device 0 which your system is likely to assume) ?

Comment: In order to confirm, please try to *aplay* whatever .wav file specifying  **--device=hw:0,5** on the command line (or hw:0,6 or hw:0,7 depending on the hdmi port used)

Comment: I tried `speaker-test -l5 -D plughw:0,5`, `speaker-test -l5 -D plughw:0,6` and `speaker-test -l5 -D plughw:0,7`, added the output above. Yes, once sound is working, ideally the default sound device should be HDMI, but I still get no sound.

Comment: I get this error: `channel count not available` when running aplay on each of those cards:

`
█[coolby][~][1]$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Rear_Center.wav --device=hw:0,7
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Rear_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1358: Channels count non available
█`

Comment: I tried multiple `-c` options, like `-c1`, -c2`, but I still always get `Channels count non available` with `aplay`

Comment: Please run *alsamixer* , F6 to select the soundcard, increase all available sliders to maximum and retry your speakertest on device 0,5

Comment: Update, I had also posted this on debian forums, someone suggested trying out the debian testing image, and sound did work out of the box: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=158135

Comment: haha ! the driver is still experimental… Good to know, I should have checked for that first. Happy it works for you. And please don't wait for any other one to eventually do it : Post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question on the [debian forums](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=158135):

In that forum, user FreewheelinFrank suggested trying out a debian testing [image](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-live-builds/amd64/iso-hybrid/) after mentioning that support for the ESSX8336 chip/codec is still under development. On this testing image, audio worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem on MX23 (Debian 12 based). MX23 uses pipewire-pulse.

I had to go to the Volume Control or System Tray Volume Control, and select Built-in Audio Profile: Pro Audio.  After that, I had sound.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually tried selecting `Pro Audio` as the default profile via `pavucontrol -> pipewire-pulse`, but this did not help. I did find a working solution in the debian forums, which I will be posting it shortly.